# Magento order email values

Tags: magento-1.9, orders, email, order-email

Is there somewhere or somehow a list with the things you can define in your transactional e-mails from magento.

For example, you can get the total price with:`{{var order.getGrandTotal()}}` and the name with `{{var order.getCustomerName()}}`.

I want to redesign all the e-mails that are send through Magento 1.9 and want to know which how and which values i can load in the e-mails.

Another question besides this: how can i get the prices with a decimal number, now i have **199 but i want 199,00**. This is how i get the value: `{{var order.getGrandTotal()}}`

Regards,
Robert

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the some predefined variables :

Items of the shipping address :

```
{{var order.getShippingAddress().getName()}} Get the first and last name
{{var order.getShippingAddress().getPrefix()}}
{{var order.getShippingAddress().getFirstName()}}
{{var order.getShippingAddress().getMiddleName()}}
{{var order.getShippingAddress().getLastName()}}
{{var order.getShippingAddress().getSuffix()}}
{{var order.getShippingAddress().getStreet1()}}
{{var order.getShippingAddress().getStreet2()}}
{{var order.getShippingAddress().getCity()}}
{{var order.getShippingAddress().getRegion()}}
{{var order.getShippingAddress().getPostcode()}}
{{var order.getShippingAddress().getCountry()}} Get the country’s ID
{{var order.getShippingAddress().getCountryModel().getName()}} Get the country’s full name
{{var order.getShippingAddress().getRegion()}}
{{var order.getShippingAddress().getTelephone()}}
```

– Other

```
{{var addAllLink}}
{{var alertGrid}}
{{var billingAddress.format(‘html’)}}
{{var checkoutType}}
{{var comment}}
{{var creditmemo.id}}
{{var creditmemo.increment_id}}
{{var data.comment}}
{{var data.email}}
{{var data.name}}
{{var data.telephone}}
{{var dateAndTime}}
{{var invoice.id}}
{{var invoice.increment_id}}
{{var invoice.created_at}}
{{var items}}
{{var items_html}}
{{var message}}
{{var name}}
{{var order.customer_email}}
{{var order.getBillingAddress().format(‘html’)}}
{{var order.getBillingAddress().getName()}}
{{var order.getCreatedAtFormated(‘long’)}}
{{var order.getCustomerName()}}
{{var order.getCustomerFirstname()}}
{{var order.getCustomerLastname()}}
{{var order.getEmailCustomerNote()}} Currently unknwon how to test this variable for being set/empty
{{var order.getShippingDescription()}}
{{var order.getStatusLabel()}}
{{var order.getStoreGroupName()}}
{{var order.id}}
{{var order.increment_id}}
{{var password}}
{{var payment_html}}
{{var paymentMethod}}
{{var product_name}}
{{var product_url}}
{{var reason}} Reason for payment failure
{{var shipment.increment_id}}
{{var shippingAddress.format(‘html’)}}
{{var shippingMethod}}
{{var total}}
{{var user.name}}
{{var viewOnSiteLink}}
{{var warnings}}
{{var billing.name}}
```

For more [viste here](http://www.justwebdevelopment.com/blog/transactional-emails-variable-magento/) and [here.](http://www.parenttechnology.com/blog/magento-commerce/237-email-variables-for-magento.html)

Comment: Is there also a way to get the decimals within the price, now i het 199, but I need 199,00?